# Firestore allow list if a specific field is provided

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I've been searching a lot and I can't find anything on the matter.
Take a collection of **post comments** which is readable by **logged in** users only.

How do I write the security rules for the **list** operation in order to allow listing only when trying to fetch comments on a specific post. Query is as simple as follows:

```
let query = store.comments
    .where( 'postId', '==', postId )
    .orderBy( 'createdAt', 'desc' )
    .limit(10)
    .get()
```

I'm worried about people simply fetching comments with **no specific postId** in mind. So I've limited the amount of queried documents to **max. 10 per request**, as well as **needing to be logged in** when doing so, but, for trying to allow listing only when **postId** is present, I have tried so many variants of which none worked.

```
match /comments/{key} {
  allow list: if isLoggedIn() && request.query.limit <= 10 && request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['postId'])
}
```

Doesn't work.

```
allow list: if isLoggedIn() && request.query.limit <= 10 && request.resource.data.postId is string
```

Also not working.

```
allow list: if isLoggedIn() && request.query.limit <= 10 && request.resource.data.postId == resouce.data.postId
```

Still nothing. Tried with **hasAll** and **hasOnly**, still no.
What I think happens is that **request.resource.data** doesn't actually exist when simply **listing** documents.

I know you can check the **query.orderBy**, but that doesn't help in my case.

Please advise

Comment: Note: I know I could just change the comments collection to be under each post document. But given I started it like this, I'm just wondering if there's any solution to it, otherwise I'll refactor my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with `request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['postId'])` is currently not supported.  Note that the API document says of [request.resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource):

> The new resource value, **present on write requests only.**

Security rules don't provide access to the data into the query filters.  That is to say, there is no expression that can require a certain named filter is present in order to execute the query.  (Though you can, of course, check that the *value* of a filter is valid by [comparing the existing document field values to known strings or variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).)

As you suggested in your comment, you should organize the data using postId as the document ID of the collection.  That would force the client to know a postId of a document, as long as you disallow `list` access on that collection (which would deny all queries that are not just document gets).

Comment: Yup, by the time you wrote that, I already refactored it. Not that big of a change anyway, the index works just fine too. Will probably have to swap it to a collection group in case I would need to find user's comments on different posts.